# Add object name to field inside object

Tags: javascript, oop, functional-programming, lodash

Lets say I have an object of objects that looks like this

```
const randomObj = {
  myObj: { id: "1", value: "random string", text: "random text"},
  otherObj: { id: "2", value: "random string 2", text: "random text 2"}
}
```

And I want to iterate through each object and its values, but add an additional field to the object

```
const newObj = { ..._.mapValues(randomObj) }
```

expected output

```
newObj: {
          myObj: { id: "1", value: "random string", text: "random text"},
          otherObj: { id: "2", value: "random string 2", text: "random text 2"},
        }
```

desired output

```
 newObj: {
         myObj: { id: "1", value: "random string", text: "random text", objectId: "myObj"},
         otherObj: { id: "2", value: "random string 2", text: "random text 2", objectId: "otherObj"},
         }
```

How do I add that additional field, where the additional field would be the name of the object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `_.mapValues()` iteratee is called with the value of the property as the 1st parameter, the key as the 2nd, and the entire object as the 3rd. Use object spread to create a new object with the key as the `objectId`.

```js
const randomObj = {
  myObj: { id: "1", value: "random string", text: "random text"},
  otherObj: { id: "2", value: "random string 2", text: "random text 2"}
}

const newObj = _.mapValues(randomObj, (v, k) => ({
  ...v,
  objectId: k
}))

console.log(newObj)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-WFN04846sdKMIP5LKNphMaWzU7YpMyCU245etK3g/2ARYbPK9Ub18eG+ljU96qKRCWh+quCY7yefSmlkQw1ANQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Without lodash you can use `Object.entries()` to convert the object to an array of `[key, value]` pairs, map pairs, and then convert the array of pairs back to an object using `Object.fromEntries()`.

```js
const randomObj = {
  myObj: { id: "1", value: "random string", text: "random text"},
  otherObj: { id: "2", value: "random string 2", text: "random text 2"}
}

const newObj = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(randomObj)
    .map(([k ,v])  => [k, {
      ...v,
      objectId: k
    }])
)

console.log(newObj)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const randomObj = {
  myObj: { id: "1", value: "random string", text: "random text"},
  otherObj: { id: "2", value: "random string 2", text: "random text 2"}
}


Object.keys(randomObj).forEach(key => randomObj[key].objectId = key);

console.log(randomObj);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using native methods Object.entries() and Array#reduce() is just about as easy as using lodash

```js
const randomObj = {
  myObj: { id: "1", value: "random string", text: "random text"},
  otherObj: { id: "2", value: "random string 2", text: "random text 2"}
},

res = Object.entries(randomObj).reduce((a,[k,v])=>(a[k] = {...v, objectId:k},a),{})

console.log(res)
```